# CKEditor filters 'class' attribute from table

Tags: javascript, web, ckeditor

I'm trying to allow the class attribute on a table without allowing all tags in html.

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

I've tried several things but none of them are working, as the editor still filters the class attribute.

I've tried:

```
table[class];

table[class](*);

table[class](*);table[class]{*};

*[class](*);

*(*);

*(*);*{*};
```

All with no result, any suggestions. Or has anyone run in to the same problem?

Kind regards,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`config.extraAllowedContent = 'table(*)';`

Read more about Allowed Content Rules format: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules

Comment: Yes this one did it! Thank you very much :D